# Nginx: possible to generate redirect based on proxy_pass response?

Tags: nginx

Currently I have a system with a number of different nodes and I want to do the following:

1. Proxy pass a request (A simple GET) and receive a response with a body that contains a URL
2. Redirect the client's original request to this URL (the one in the response body)

In a nutshell - I'm receiving a client request, doing another request to lookup the URL they *should* be going to and then redirecting their original request to the correct location.

Would this be possible with Nginx or?

Comment: Could you add some more details about the requests / responses? Are the parameters you're referring to stored in the header, or body of the response?

Comment: @gf_ I have added a few more details as requested

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with Nginx.

Problems like this are usually solved with application with an app server that runs behind Nginx.